# Memory Problem with Modules and NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, scoping, memory

I'm using NDSolve inside a module, and I appear to have a memory leak.  The relevant code is:

```
  mpl = 1/Sqrt[6.70837*10^-39];
  gsT = 106.75;
  Sup[ΛI_?NumericQ, ΓI_?NumericQ] := 
  Module[{a, ρr, Trad, tf, s, t},
     ClearAll[tf]; ClearAll[Trad]; ClearAll[s];
     tf = 10/ΓI;
     ClearAll[a]; ClearAll[ρr];
     s = NDSolve[{a'[t] == a[t]*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2) (ρr[t] + ΛI^4/a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])], ρr'[t] + 4*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2) (ρr[t] + ΛI^4/a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])] ρr[t] == ΓI ΛI^4/a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t], a[0] == 1, ρr[0] == 0}, {a, ρr}, {t, 0, tf}, MaxStepFraction -> 10^-5, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
    {a = a /. s[[1]], ρr = ρr /. s[[1]]};
    Trad[t_] := (30/(π^2 gsT) ρr[t])^(1/4);
    Trad[tf]*a[tf]]
```

(I then evaluate `Sup[x,y]` for a variety of `x` and `y` values; actually, my goal is to make a contour plot of it.)

As you can see, I'm explicitly clearing `a[t]` and `Rho[t]` before I call `NDSolve`; however, these don't appear to get deleted after the module evaluates.  Looking at the global variables, I have `a$1058`, `a$1186`, and so on.  This is causing my memory usage to spiral out of control.

The problem seems to be that `DownValues` are being assigned to these functions and so they're not getting cleared.  (I have set `$HistoryLength` to zero.)

How can I get the module to really, truly clear these functions?

Comment: See the last paragraph under Module -- Advanced Uses [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/569/12).  It's likely due to that.  The solution is to clear these variables *after* (not before) they've been used.  Try ending the `Module` with `result =  Trad[tf]*a[tf]; Clear[...]; result`, where you clear everything that doesn't seem to get cleared properly.

Comment: @Szabolcs I tried that (editing the end of the module to be `result = Trad[tf]*a[tf];
ClearAll[tf]; ClearAll[Trad]; ClearAll[s]; ClearAll[a]; ClearAll[\
\[Rho]r];
result` ) which didn't work- I still get multiple copes in Global`

Comment: Do not use `ClearAll` because it removes the `Temporary` attribute.  Use simply `Clear` instead.  I don't remember all the details of how this works, but see also the comment discussion under the answer I linked.

Comment: Sorry, I see that doesn't work either, but at least it prevents the memory from filling up ...

Comment: @Szabolcs I found that Remove worked, although ClearAll and Clear didn't...not sure why.

Comment: That's because `Clear` removes definitions associated with the symbol, but it doesn't remove the symbol itself.  `Remove` removed the symbol and replaced references to it (if they exist) with "something else" that is formatted as `Removed["name"]` but is really a special object.  About why this happens: it's strange that e.g. `a` isn't cleared properly because it doesn't in fact have a downvalue, only an ownvalue.  It is likely that `NDSolve` creates some internal structures that hold references to the symbols that were used in the equation.  It might help if ...

Comment: you don't assign the interpolating functions to the same symbol that you used inside `NDSolve`.  It might also help to use `Block` instead of `Module`, as `Block` doesn't create temporary symbols, it just makes definitions temporary.  The usual problem with using Block instead of Module is when you pass symbols to the function (the arguments `x` and `y`) that have names identical with something you use internally.  This cannot happen here because of `?NumericQ`.  So Block would be appropriate.  All that said, it is still very annoying that this problem happens ...

Comment: [This is the workaround](http://pastebin.com/Yup6TFk6) I would use ... hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!  That does what I need.

Comment: Here is a stripped down example showing the variable leakage. `sup[] := Module[{a, t, aa},  aa = nds[{a'[t] == 1, a[0] == 1}, a, {t, 0, 1}];  4];
Table[{sup[], Information["a*"]}, {3}]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau `Module[{a}, a';]` is sufficient to trigger it.  So is it `Derivative` to blame?  Removing it makes the problem go away.

Comment: @Daniel `Do[Module[{a}, a'; ClearSystemCache[]], {10}]` only leaks one symbol instead of 10.  Removing `ClearSystemCache[]` will cause it to leak 10.  `Derivative` keeps references to these symbols in some cache?

Comment: @Szabolcs This issue regarding `Derivative` was also pointed out to me in house yesterday evening (and is noted in the bug report).  I was not aware of the caching aspect. Will note that as well and maybe it will get attention. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 7):

It is a little known fact and probably not well documented, but since version 9 one can use just strings as variables (dependent and independent) in NDSolve, which in this case helps to solve the memory problem in a rather elegant way:

```
mpl=1/Sqrt[6.70837*10^-39];
gsT=106.75;
Sup[LamdaI_?NumericQ,GammaI_?NumericQ]:=Module[{
        a,rhor,Trad,tf,s,t
    },
    tf=10/GammaI;
    s=NDSolve[{
            "a"'["t"]=="a"["t"]*Sqrt[(8 Pi)/(3 mpl^2) ("rhor"["t"]+LamdaI^4/"a"["t"]^3 Exp[-GammaI "t"])],
            "rhor"'["t"]+4*Sqrt[(8 Pi)/(3 mpl^2) ("rhor"["t"]+LamdaI^4/"a"["t"]^3 Exp[-GammaI "t"])] "rhor"["t"]==GammaI LamdaI^4/"a"["t"]^3 Exp[-GammaI "t"],"a"[0]==1,"rhor"[0]==0
        },{"a","rhor"},{"t",0,tf},
        MaxStepFraction->10^-5,MaxSteps->10^6
    ];
    a="a"/.s[[1]];
    rhor="rhor"/.s[[1]];
    Trad=Function[t,(30/(Pi^2 gsT) rhor[t])^(1/4)];
    Trad[tf]*a[tf]
]
```

note that I used a pure function instead of `DownValues` to define `Trad` which is also a trick which helps to prevent the known `Module` leakages. For me this function does not leak any variables anymore and I think should be free of memory leaks as well. Of course one could do the same thing in a programmatical way, but that needs some care to prevent leakage as for some reason even the evaluation of just the derivatives seems to be enough to make the local variables survive as Szabolcs has found out...

*Note* this seems to be an unwanted feature which just happend to work by accident. Newer versions (I think starting from 11.2) strings are not accepted as variable names anymore, of course making my answer useless for these newer versions...

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore in Mathematica 11. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/172452/34148

Comment: @LouisYang correct, I will add that to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments that Szabolcs gave, Clear and ClearAll are ineffective, but using Remove works.  So now the module reads:

```
    Sup[\[CapitalLambda]I_?NumericQ, \[CapitalGamma]I_?NumericQ] := 
    Module[{a, \[Rho]r, Trad, tf, s, t, result},
      tf = 10/\[CapitalGamma]I;
      s = NDSolve[{a'[t] ==a[t]*Sqrt[(8 \[Pi])/(3 mpl^2) (\[Rho]r[t] + \[CapitalLambda]I^4/a[t]^3 Exp[-\[CapitalGamma]I t])], \[Rho]r'[t] +4*Sqrt[(8 \[Pi])/(3 mpl^2) (\[Rho]r[t] + \[CapitalLambda]I^4/a[t]^3 Exp[-\[CapitalGamma]I t])] \[Rho]r[t] == \[CapitalGamma]I \[CapitalLambda]I^4/a[t]^3 Exp[-\[CapitalGamma]I t],a[0] == 1, \[Rho]r[0] == 0}, {a, \[Rho]r}, {t, 0, tf},MaxStepFraction -> 10^-5, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
     {a = a /. s[[1]], \[Rho]r = \[Rho]r /. s[[1]]};
     Trad[t_] := (30/(\[Pi]^2 gsT) \[Rho]r[t])^(1/4);
     result = Trad[tf]*a[tf];
     Remove[tf]; Remove[Trad]; Remove[s]; Remove[a]; Remove[\[Rho]r]; Remove[t];
     result
     ]
```

I'm still not entirely sure why Remove works when the others didn't, but it does.

Comment: Could it be due to "`ClearAll` also removes all properties and definitions, but leaves the symbol intact" (from documentation of `Remove`)?

Comment: `ClearAll` does remove Temporary, which as @Szabolcs said could be a problem, but `Clear` doesn't have this issue, and doesn't work either.

Comment: I think @Mahdi means that, `ClearAll` will clear things inside the symbol, but won't destroy the symbol. Actually this is not related to `Module`, just try `a = 1; Clear["a"]; ?a` and `a = 1; Remove["a"]; ?a`. BTW I think using `Clear` or `ClearAll` instead of `Remove` here is OK, because though the temporary variables are still there, they're now empty, which is usually not a big problem.

Answer (score 2):

The reason `Clear` did not work is because the variables are referenced from the system cache. You need to `ClearSystemCache[]` as well. (Or wait for the references to get cleared from the cache themselves.)

This thus works:

```
Sup[ΛI_?NumericQ, ΓI_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{a, ρr, Trad, tf, s, t, result}, tf = 10/ΓI;
  s = NDSolve[{a'[t] == 
  a[t]*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2) (ρr[
        t] + ΛI^4/
         a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])], ρr'[t] + 
   4*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2) (ρr[
         t] + ΛI^4/
          a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])] ρr[
     t] == ΓI ΛI^4/
    a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t], 
 a[0] == 1, ρr[0] == 0}, {a, ρr}, {t, 0, tf}, 
MaxStepFraction -> 10^-5, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
{a = a /. s[[1]], ρr = ρr /. s[[1]]};
Trad[t_] := (30/(π^2 gsT) ρr[t])^(1/4);
result = Trad[tf]*a[tf];
Clear[tf, Trad, s, a, ρr, t];
ClearSystemCache[];
result]
```

Edit:
In fact, one can (at least in 11.1.1) forgo the `Clear` entirely and just `ClearSystemCache`. This makes me wonder why  it is necessary to do this at all, since in principle the system cache should clear old entries by itself.

Answer (score 0):

The string as a function name method by @Albert Retey no longer work in MMA 11. But `Block[]` seems to work in this specific case.

```
  mpl = 1/Sqrt[6.70837*10^-39];
  gsT = 106.75;
  Sup[ΛI_?NumericQ, ΓI_?NumericQ] := 
  Block[{a, ρr, Trad, tf, s, t},
     tf = 10/ΓI;
     s = NDSolve[{a'[t] == a[t]*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2) (ρr[t] + ΛI^4/a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])], ρr'[t] + 4*Sqrt[(8 π)/(3 mpl^2) (ρr[t] + ΛI^4/a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t])] ρr[t] == ΓI ΛI^4/a[t]^3 Exp[-ΓI t], a[0] == 1, ρr[0] == 0}, {a, ρr}, {t, 0, tf}, MaxStepFraction -> 10^-5, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
    {a = a /. s[[1]], ρr = ρr /. s[[1]]};
    Trad[t_] := (30/(π^2 gsT) ρr[t])^(1/4);
    Trad[tf]*a[tf]]
```

Try to run it by

```
Table[{Sup[10^16, 10^8], Information["a$*"]}, {3}]
```

You should not see any new `a$XXXXX` generated.