# NDSolve in Mathematica 11 don't accept string as a function name?

Tags: differential-equations

```
NDSolve[{"a"''[t] + "a"[t] == 0, "a"'[0] == 0, "a"[0] == 1}, "a", {t, 0, 10}]
```

This code works in Mathematica 10 and below but in Mathematica 11, I got the error message:

```
NDSolve::dsfun: "a" cannot be used as a function.
```

Is this a bug or just the new limitation?

---

The reason I use string as function name is because it can avoid memory problem for using `NDSolve` in `Module`. See the question and answer here https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/78382/34148

Comment: I never knew a function name can be string except now. But may be someone at WRI finally noticed this and decided it was bad idea and removed this hidden feature? I have no idea why any one would want to write code using strings for function names to start with, even if it possible, as it leads to convoluted code to say the least. But you are correct, I verified it worked on 10.4 and not on 11.3.

Comment: Because I try to avoid the memory problem. See my new edited.

Comment: @LouisYang This was never intended to work (at least starting from 10.0) - see my updated answer

Answer (score 6):

#### This is a bug in 10.0 (or earlier) up to 11.1 that has been resolved in 11.2

From the documentation of [`NDSolve::dsfun`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/message/DSolve/dsfun.html) (this exists at least since 10.2):

> This message is generated when a number or a string is used as the name of a function in DSolve or NDSolve.

So it appears as if this was never intended to work, and the oversight was finally fixed in 11.2.

In case you were not aware, some messages are documented on a separate page:

[image]

Comment: I think the question was asking, why it worked before and not now.

Comment: @Nasser Well, it answers the question whether it's a bug or not. Unfortunately, I don't have MMA 10 installed, so I can't tell how the documentation looks there

Comment: in version 10.4, there is no error message and it works ok. So no message to trace as you show.

Comment: @Nasser Does the message exist? If yes, what does it say? Could be that it was always supposed to fail

Comment: I checked, and could not find the message you found in 10.4, here is screen shot fyi ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pqRtb.png)

Comment: @Nasser Interesting… So it seems to be a new limitation - I'll add a note to the answer

Comment: @Nasser Ok, found an installation of MMA 10.0 - the message is already there with the same description, apparently the error just wasn't detected properly up to 11.1. - I've updated the answer accordingly

Comment: OK, I thought this is the new feature introduced in MMA 9. Now, I will have to find another way to avoid memory leakage for NDSolve in function.

Comment: Just a side note, `dsfun` warning exists at least from _v3_: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVA8Y.png As mentioned by @LouisYang , this seems to be a feature introduced silently in _v9_ but removed later…